# how to remove duplicate rows in R within Arrow?

Tags: r, distinct, arrow-functions, apache-arrow

I work with the arrow dataset to reduce the RAM usage but I met with the following problem.
I need to remove duplicate rows. With dplyr I can do it using `distinct()` but this function doesn't supported in Arrow.
Any ideas?

Following to recommendations I wrote the following code

```
Sales_2021 <- Sales_2021 %>%
  group_by(`Cust-Item-Loc`) %>%
  arrange(desc(SBINDT)) %>% 
  distinct(`Cust-Item-Loc`, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  
  collect()
```

and got the **Error message**

```
Error: `distinct()` with `.keep_all = TRUE` not supported in Arrow
```

How can I `slice` the first rows?

The advice with `filter(!duplicate())` is not working as well.

```
Sales_2021 <- Sales_2021 %>%
  group_by(`Cust-Item-Loc`) %>%
  arrange(desc(SBINDT)) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(`Cust-Item-Loc`)) %>%
  
  collect()
```

**Error message**

```
Error: Filter expression not supported for Arrow Datasets: !duplicated(`Cust-Item-Loc`)
Call collect() first to pull data into R.
```

Comment: Try with `df1 %>% filter(!duplicated(yourcol)) %>% collect()`

Comment: `distinct()` has been supported in arrow since version [6.0.0](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/news/index.html#arrow-600) (November 2021).

Comment: grislepak, seeing as how @NealRichardson is the `arrow` package author, that's about as authoritative as you can get. What version of arrow are you using? `packageDescription("arrow")` should give that, and if you're using below-6.0.0 then either update or explain why you need that version. If you are beyond that version, though, you need to augment your question with a reproducible example, since on the face of it, it seems that your feature-request has been in place for almost a year.

Comment: Version: 9.0.0.2

Comment: @NealRichardson I use the Arrow package Version 9.0.0.2 but the distinct function is not supported. I add the Error message to the question.

Comment: Yes, distinct with .keep_all is not yet supported. https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/13934 implements that, probably coming in the 11.0 release.

Comment: This request is still relevant, and unfortunately has not made it in as of `arrow_14.0.0.1`. [arrow#13934](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/13934) was closed ("untouched for a while"), and the previous PR [arrow#29642](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/29642) is also quite stale. @NealRichardson, is there an update for this question and this request?