# Alternatives for distinct(.keep_all = TRUE) in arrow?

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

I have a larger than memory arrow dataset created by open_dataset() from partitioned parquet files that I need to use `distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)` on.  I need to keep the computation on disk, therefore I'm using arrow to speed things up and not crash my R session.

I want to keep rows that have distinct values in columns a and b.

**Example**

```
df <- tibble(a = c(1,1,2,2),
             b = c(1,1,2,1),
             c = c("x", "y", "z", "a")) %>%
  arrow_table()


df %>% 
  distinct(a, b, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This results in:
`Error: distinct() with .keep_all = TRUE not supported in Arrow`

**Desired Output**

An arrow dataset with the following values.

```
  a     b c    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 x    
2     2     2 z    
3     2     1 a
```

[I see others have had similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184665/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-in-r-within-arrow) but it doesn't seem like arrow plans to incorporate use of `.keep_all` [(see closed issue)](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/404).

`base::duplicated()` would also work but it's not supported by arrow either. Any thoughts on how to work around this without using `collect()` (which crashes my R session)? TIA!

Comment: Do you really need `distinct`, or can you do a grouped `slice`?

Comment: Until grouped-slice and other group operations are supported in `arrow`, there is no workaround short of collecting all data.

Answer (score -1):

As commented, a grouped `slice` operation will likely do instead.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = c(1,1,2,2),
             b = c(1,1,2,1),
             c = c("x", "y", "z", "a"))

df %>% 
  group_by(a, b) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   a, b [3]
#>       a     b c    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     1 x    
#> 2     2     1 a    
#> 3     2     2 z
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-28 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response. This won't work as [slicing groups isn't supported in arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/dev/r/reference/acero.html)

Comment: mhovd, I think the use of `arrow_table(.)` in the sample data is as strict a requirement as any (to mimic full-up lazy operations in dplyr/arrow).